# Retrieve data from firebase using two queries into Recylerview without clearing the first query

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort the firebase and populate both data retrieved in one recyclerview. I want to query the database twice by showing at the top all the item that was added 2 days ago plus I want to show items added 4 days ago.

What i am doing.

I wrote the code to query my Database using order by

```
databaseReference.child("Posts").orderByChild("date").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { if (snapshot.exists()){.....
```

I am able to successfully retieve the data from this query into recyclerview with the first data showing all the post created in the last two days.

I have been confused about how i can some like "also show data that was created in the last 4 days" into that same recyclewview without clearing the first on.

What i tried

I created another Database reference and queried the database with the second order by post created in the last four days and also added the retrieved data into the recylerview, the result cleared the first data retrieved.

Comment: Why not using `startAt()` method?

Comment: I am using Collection.Shuffle(list) so it will mix both the data from 2 days ago and 4 days ago, whereas i want to have post from two days ago, shuffled at the top, and at the end of that list and on same recyclerview the remaining data will be post from 4 days ago also shuffled